# Jquery tools overlay not working properly on dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I don't know if this is a known problem or if I am just doing this wrong but when I open the JQuery Tools overlay on dynamically generated elements the close button doesn't work.

I tried 3 different combinations.

1.

```
$(document).on("click", "a[rel]", function() { $("a[rel]").overlay(); });
```

2.

```
$("a[rel]").overlay();
$(document).on("click", "a[rel]", function() { $("a[rel]").overlay(); });
```

3.

```
setting the .overlay() on document ready and in my add item event.
```

Any ideas why the close button isn't working? The overlay opens just fine for the new elements it's just nothing happens when I press close. There aren't any console errors either.

Thanks.

EDIT - I created a jfiddle but it's has it's own problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/TjQAQ/

Comment: Create a fiddle so we can reproduce your problem..

Comment: I made one but I can't the overlay to work at all in it.  -> http://jsfiddle.net/TjQAQ/

Comment: That was enough for me to work on an answer, as a tip if you want to get answers try to provide fiddles, even not working ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#add').click( function() { 
       $('<a rel="#overlay">New Overlay Trigger</a>').appendTo('body').overlay();
   }); 

   $("a[rel]").overlay();     
});
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TjQAQ/2/)

Comment: Now if I am using backbone with underscore templates how can I do this? The line I add my new items is:   
$('ul#adminSpaceImage', this.el).append(this.template(item.toJSON()));

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot I was using backbone. Any ideas? Thanks again for replying so quickly. I accept your answer anyway.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. I just needed to find the last selector and call .overlay on it. Thanks again!